# Proof of $\sum_{k=0}^n k \text{Pr}(X=k) = \sum^{n-1}_{k=0} \text{Pr}(X>k) -n \text{Pr}(X>n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ is a random variable defined in $\mathbb N$. How can I prove that  for all $n\in \mathbb N$?

> - $ \text E(X) =\sum_{k=0}^n k \text{Pr}(X=k) = \sum^{n-1}_{k=0} \text{Pr}(X>k)  -n \text{Pr}(X>n)$
> - $\text E(X) =\sum_{k=0}^n k \text{Pr}(X=k)=\sum_{k\ge 0} \text{Pr}(X>k) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part $a)$, use Thomas' hint. You get
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}k(P(X>i-1)-P(X>i)).
$$

This develops as $P(X>0)-P(X>1)+2P(X>1)-2P(X>2)+3P(X>2)-3P(X>3)+\cdots nP(X>n-1)-nP(X>n)$

for part $b)$:

In general, you have

$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty P(X\geq i).$

You can show this as follow:
$$
 \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty P(X\geq i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{j=i}^\infty P(X = j)
$$

Switch the order of summation gives
\begin{align}
 \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty P(X\geq i)&=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{i=1}^j P(X = j)\\
                   &=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty j\, P(X = j)\\
                   &=\mathbb{E}(X)
\end{align}

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}iP(X=i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty P(X\geq i)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} P(X> i)$$

Comment: I was proving the wrong thing, when I saw your edit :P

Comment: Hi @Jean-Sébastien, can you explain the part you switch the summation a little more? while in the first sum Pr(X = 1) appears once, in the switched one, however, Pr(x = 1) appears many times which seems not to be equal to the first one.

Comment: @Sepehr If you look at it carefully, it only appears once. The second summation is of index $i$, while the inside sum has not $i$, just a $j$. this is why it becomes $j\times P(X=j$) in the second line. Try writing the first two sums in a array, lines being on $j$ and column on $i$. First line sums each line while second sums each column. I'll edit if you can't get it.

Comment: Hi @Jean-Sébastien, I see what you are saying. Now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! glad it could help

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $Pr(X=k) = Pr(X>k-1)-Pr(X>k)$